# Familiar categorical limits viewed elegantly as weighted limits?

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Are there any limits in ordinary category theory that are more elegantly seen as weighted limits?

In $\mathsf{Set}$-enriched category theory, one can say that the limit of $\mathbf{J} \xrightarrow{D} \mathscr{A}$ weighted by $\mathbf{J} \xrightarrow{W} \mathsf{Set}$ can be equivalently expressed as an ordinary limit of $D$ precomposed with the projection functor from the elements of $W$. And an ordinary limit is of course a weighted limit with constant weight.

I'm looking for examples along the lines of the following. The kernel pair of $f:a \to a' \in \operatorname{Ar}\mathscr{A}$ is the limit of $\mathbf{2} \xrightarrow{f} \mathscr{A}$ weighted by $\mathbf{2} \to \mathsf{Set}$ landing on the arrow sending the doubleton to the singleton. (Riehl's *Categorical Homotopy Theory*, page 100)

Of course colimits are welcome as well; they're limits just like you and me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any limits in ordinary category theory that are more elegantly seen as weighted limits?

There are many examples of *constructions* in category theory which are best seen as weighted co/limits, but the notion of weighted co/limits is inherently higher-dimensional, so plain 1-category theory and plain 1-dimensional limits can't capture the intrinsic "2-dimensional aspect" hidden in these constructions.

The slogan is
$$
\text{limits} : 
\text{category theory} =
\text{weighted limits} : 
\text{enriched category theory}
$$
so that the "right" notion of co/limit when you "fatten" category theory into *enriched* category theory fattens the weight accordingly.

Among Riehl's examples, I think those coming from algebraic topology are the most inspiring to see weighted co/limits in action:

1. The *mapping cone* of $f\colon X\to Y$ is the weighted colimit of $f$, regarded as a functor $\{0\to 1\}\to {\bf Top}$, with the weight $W\colon \{0\to 1\}\to \bf sSet$ sending $i\in\{0,1\}$ to $\Delta[i]$.
2. The *suspension* of a space $X$ is the homotopy colimit of the diagram $\text{pt}\leftarrow X \to \text{pt}$, and homotopy co/limits can be viewed as weighted co/limits in nice model categories (a nice category of spaces *is* a nice model category), since
3. every homotopy colimit $\text{ho}\varinjlim X_i$ of a diagram $X\colon J\to \bf Spaces$ can be written as a weigthed colimit
   $$
   \{N(J_{/-}), X\} = \int^{j\in J} N(J_{/j})\otimes X_j
   $$
   (you can also regard this as a "replacement" procedure: there is a canonical weak equivalence $N(J_{/j}) \to \text{pt}$ in a suitable model category of functors $J\to \bf sSet$).
4. The *lax colimit* of a functor $F\colon {\cal A}\to \bf Cat$ coincides with the weighted colimit of $F$ by the functor ${\cal A} \to \bf Cat$ sending $a$ to the slice ${\cal A}_{a/}$ (arrows $a\to x$ as objects); but this is precisely the Grothendieck construction associated to $F$ (since there is an embeddng ${\bf Set}\to {\bf Cat}$, when $F$ has discrete values this amounts to the "category of elements" construction for the presheaf $F\colon \mathcal A\to \bf Set$)!
5. Several examples of 2-categorical limits like inserters (equalize two 1-cells up to a 2-cell), equifiers (equalize two parallel 2-cells), comma objects (the lax notion of pullback) admit a description in terms of weigthed co/limits: you can read the wonderfully clear paper by kelly, "[Elementary observations on 2-categorical limits](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/elementary_observations_on_2ca.html)".
6. Co/ends are co/limits of functors $T\colon {\cal A}^\text{op}\times {\cal A}\to \cal B$, weighted by the hom functor $\hom : {\cal A}^\text{op}\times {\cal A}\to \bf Set$. This is described in Riehl's book and in [my notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v2.pdf) (Example 4.11, but I copied from Emily!) on coend calculus.

Whew! Hope this long list helped a little bit. :-)

Comment: I gained these points and had the time to answer first only because Zhen Lin is in vacation :-)

Comment: I don't see how weighted limits are any more intrinsically 2-categorical than ordinary limits.

Answer (score 3):

A nice example is the colimit expressing an arbitrary presheaf as a colimit of representables. It's convenient to express this as a weighted colimit for some purposes, and necessary to describe the appropriate generalization to enriched categories.