# Weighted limits in ordinary category theory are ordinary limits from the category of elements

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, limits-colimits

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885386/familiar-categorical-limits-viewed-elegantly-as-weighted-limits), the OP says that

> In $\mathsf{Set}$-enriched category theory, one can say that the limit of $\mathbf{J} \xrightarrow{D} \mathscr{A}$ weighted by $\mathbf{J} \xrightarrow{W} \mathsf{Set}$ can be equivalently expressed as an ordinary limit of $D$ precomposed with the projection functor from the elements of $W$.

While I believe and understand the statement, I would like a reference for it, with some context. Can anyone point me to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find detailed explanations in either

- Section 3.4 of Kelly's "Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory", available [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html).
- Section 7.1 of Riehl's "Categorical Homotopy Theory", available [here](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/cathtpy/).
- Proposition 4.1.9 of Loregian's "Coend calculus", available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503).